# Time capsule - external drive via Ethernet

Tags: time-capsule

I just bought a Time capsule. At home I have a USB hard drive that I typically use to read divx from connecting it to my tv that is able to play avi files. I'm wondering if I can connect it to the TC via an Ethernet port (that the external drive has) so that it can stay connected to the tv and I can manage movies wirelessly through the capsule.

So:

```
Mac --> wifi --> time capsule.                    ## CONNECT
time capsule --> Ethernet --> HD.                 ## SHARE FILES
Tv --> USB --> HD.                                ## READ MOVIES
Mac --> wifi --> time capsule --> Ethernet --> HD ## TRANSFER FILES
```

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: A hard disk with an Ethernet port ? What kind of hard disk is that ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your external HD is actually a Network Attached Storage device. If it somehow supports simultaneous access via the network (SMB which is windows file sharing) AND plugged in to USB (to your TV) then that might work out really well. Unfortunately I don't believe that there are devices that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely the TV will see the files if you attach the drive to the Time Capsule. You'll have to determine how it wants to access files.

Time Capsule only wants to share files only from a drive connected by USB and only to any network clients. This means that your TV - ethernet - TC connection will not allow the TC to see the drive and re-share it elsewhere.

However, if you want to sequentially connect the drive for a time to the TV and then for a time to the Time Capsule all will be fine with this "hard drive time sharing plan" and either the TV or the TC will get access to the drive singly.

The Time Capsule is made to share the files to Macs and Windows PC using AFP (Apple's file sharing protocol) and SMB (Windows file sharing protocol), so it's basically can your TV access an AFP or SMB network share over ethernet (or Wi-Fi)? If so, you should be fine.

Comment: The @pistacchio speaks about the TV being connected to the disk, not to the Time Capsule.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Great catch - I was totally barking up the wrong tree here. If the hard drive is a network device, then of course you could plug it in directly and see it on any network connected computer. Whether the hard drive has a web management console or operates as a file share would govern what could be done in that case. I wonder if I should edit this or leave it be or delete it.